# Powershell v7.3 - The type or namespace name 'ICertificatePolicy' could not be found

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.3

I receive the following when using that code.  I am using visual studio code and powershell 7.2.3.

error message:

```
Add-Type: (5,36): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ICertificatePolicy' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy {
                                   ^
Add-Type: Cannot add type. Compilation errors occurred.
New-Object: 
Line |
  22 |  … vicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy
     |                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Cannot find type [TrustAllCertsPolicy]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
```

Script :

```
add-type @"
using System.Net;

using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy {

  public bool CheckValidationResult(

  ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate,

  WebRequest request, int certificateProblem) {

  return true;

  }

}

"@

[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy
```

Comment: It seems `ICertificatePolicy` and `CertificatePolicy` are [obsolete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.certificatepolicy)..